# cakephp recapthca plugin unset

Tags: validation, cakephp, recaptcha

I am trying to unset recapthca validation on a few forms but have not had any luck. I always get an error from my "recaptcha_response_field" stating that "You did not enter the words correctly. Please try again."

I need recaptcha on most of my forms but I want to skip a few. I have tried "MultivalidatableBehavior" http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/dardosordi/2008/07/29/multivalidatablebehavior-using-many-validation-rulesets-per-model but I was unable to get that to work either.

Any ideas on how I maybe able to get this to work?

https://github.com/tbsmcd/recaptcha_plugin

Thanks,
Bart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your going to have to edit the plugin behavior to do it...  This would be the easiest way to do it, you could also do it in the behavior, but this way is simple and easy.

```
//Your Controller
function add(){
$this->{$this->modelClass}->reCaptcha = true;
if(!empty($this->data)){
$this->{$this->modelClass}->save($this->data);
}
}

//Edit Recaptcha ValidateBehavior
function beforeValidate(&$model) {
if(isset($model->reCaptcha) && $model->reCaptcha){
$model->validate['recaptcha_response_field'] = array(
'checkRecaptcha' => array(
'rule' => array('checkRecaptcha', 'recaptcha_challenge_field'),
'required' => true,
'message' => 'You did not enter the words correctly. Please try again.',
),
);
}
}
```